# Walletconnect without exposing infura Id

Tags: walletconnect

I implemented walletconnect into my vue 2 webapp and everything work perfectly but it really bother me that it expose my infure id to everyone.

Is there any way to use walletconnect without using it or exposing it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to use walletconnect without using it or exposing it?

No. Someone have to provide an Ethereum node to a Dapp. There are two options

- User. You ask user to bring their own nodes. Naturally this does not work, because 99.999% of the current Dapp users do not bother to run their own nodes.
- User's wallet. Does not work with WalletConnect, because the wallet app is in a different device. Works with MetaMask because MetaMask is integrated with the web browser.
- You provide it as Dapp developer

Comment: Ok i see, i'll provide it then, thank you very much.

Comment: Please see the edit.